# What is the logic behind - and -- on git?

Tags: git

On Git commands, sometimes we use `-` and sometimes we use `--`

Do you know why?

Is there a meaning or a logic behind the use of `-` and `--` ?

Comment: What context are you referring to? Mostly theses are just command-line conventions independent of Git itself.

Comment: This has also already been answer on [ServerFault.SE](https://serverfault.com/questions/387935/whats-the-difference-betwen-the-single-dash-and-double-dash-flags-on-shell-comm)

Comment: As explained above, single-dashed options are SUPPOSED (people coming from DOS not always respect this) to be single letters options that can optionnaly be nested (`-cvf` equals `-c -v -f`) while double-dashed options specify one option at a time using a full-length keyword (`--exclude`). But this a general **UNIX** convention. It's not specific to Git.

Comment: Thank you Brian!